# How to consider all rows in agg method after grouping by columns where some values are NaN?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm tring to make a cohort analysis (I´m following [this link](http://www.gregreda.com/2015/08/23/cohort-analysis-with-python/) but adapting to my needs) I have a dataframe like this:

```
> df.head()
id          user_created_at   status_id     status_period     cohort_group
30322300    2017-12-17        30322311.0    2017-12           2017-12
30322268    2017-12-17        NaN           NaN               2017-12
12463236    2017-05-24        NaN           NaN               2017-05
16454748    2017-08-10        16455080.0    2017-08           2017-08
4100773     2017-02-24        4153065.0     2017-02           2017-02
```

I'm grouping it by `['cohort_group', 'status_period']` and use `agg` method expecting to have the count of all `id` and `status_id`.

```
df.groupby(['cohort_group', 'status_period']).grouped.agg(
                      {'id': pd.Series.nunique,
                       'status_id': pd.Series.nunique,
                      })

                                 id status_id 

cohort_group    status_period       
2015-02             2015-02       3     3.0
                    2015-03       2     2.0
                    2015-05       1     1.0
                    2015-06       1     1.0
                    2016-01       1     1.0

2015-03             2015-03       126   126.0
                    2015-05       13    13.0
                    2015-07       1     1.0
                    2016-06       1     1.0

2015-04             2015-04       120   120.0
                    2015-05       479   479.0
                    2015-06       1     1.0
...
```

As there are some rows where the status_id are `NaN` I was expecting to have a higher amount of `id` than `status_id` but I believe that after using `groupby`, the rows where `status_period` are `NaN` are not being considered, resulting in the same value for both columns.

How can I make to consider all rows in the `agg` method, even those where `status_period` are `NaN`?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas currently drops Nan values when doing groupby on non-categorical data.  One work around to this is to use `fillna` like this, see [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#na-values-in-groupby):

```
df.fillna(-1).groupby(['cohort_group','status_period']).agg(
                      {'id': pd.Series.nunique,
                       'status_id': pd.Series.nunique,
                      })
```

Output:

```
                            status_id  id
cohort_group status_period               
2017-02      2017-02              1.0   1
2017-05      -1                   1.0   1
2017-08      2017-08              1.0   1
2017-12      -1                   1.0   1
             2017-12              1.0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the data type of the column before grouping:

```
df.astype({'status_period':'str'}).groupby(['cohort_group', 'status_period']).agg(
                      {'id': pd.Series.nunique,
                       'status_id': pd.Series.nunique,
                      })
```

output:

```
                            id  status_id
cohort_group status_period
2017-02      2017-02         1        1.0
2017-05      nan             1        0.0
2017-08      2017-08         1        1.0
2017-12      2017-12         1        1.0
             nan             1        0.0
```